# Modal won't close on ajax success and won't show the success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The script sends the content of the form correctly, but when you hit the send button the modal is not closed, so it does not show the message *"Thank you for your feedback*" then.

I'm also using these libraries.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

This is the script:

```
var d = new Date();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hiddenURL").parent().parent().hide();
    $(".hiddenURL").val(window.location.href);
    $("#reportProblemButton").click(function(){
        var clone = $("#formProblemContent");

         var modalDialog = BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Report a Problem',
            "message":clone,
            "onhide":function(){
                $("#formProblemContentHidden").append(clone);
            },
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close',
                action:function(dr){
                    windows.close();
                }
            }, {
                label: 'Report Issue',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(dr){
                    if($("#g-recaptcha-response").val()!=""){
                        $.ajax({
                          'url':"/api/widget/json/get/contactDialogBoxEngine?devmode=1",
                          'method':'POST',
                          'data':$('form',clone).serialize(),
                          'success' :function(data){
                              windows.close();
                              BootstrapDialog.alert({
                                'title':'Ready!',
                                'type':BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
                                'message':'Thank you for your feedback'
                              });
                          }
                      });
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('To Continue please click on the ReCaptcha Field');
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

this is my html

```
<div style="display:none;" id="formProblemContentHidden">
    <div id="formProblemContent">
        <?php echo form("reportProblem","",$w[website_id],$w); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it that the alert message is blocking the modal?

Comment: i dont know, you can see the button here, before the footer is the blue button called "Problem with this Listing?":
https://www.opencounseling.com/united-states/tulsa/counseling-agency/catholic-charities-counseling-services-

Comment: is `windows.close()` a real thing?  it works?

Comment: yeah it close the modal when I press the X on the top right corner